# Give my app permission to trigger a factory reset

Tags: java, android, kotlin, system, android-source

I'm creating a system application on my own custom AOSP.
I have managed to install the application on system/priv-app partition and signed it using the platform keys. This have worked like a charm until I tried to implement a factory reset option in my app.

I read about device admin but I had the idea that it wouldn't be necessary because of the system privileges. So I tried implementing:

```
RecoverySystem.rebootWipeUserData(application)
```

But it throws following error:

Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR_NOTIFICATION from pid=2125, uid=10126.

Is it some permission my app is missing? Is Device administration the only way to go?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not want apps on my device that can reset the bunch.

Comment: Well It's not for the public just for my own device/build. Read the thread..

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RecoverySystem#rebootWipeUserData(android.content.Context)), it requires `Manifest.permission.REBOOT` permission.
Have you add this permission to your app?

Comment: Yes I have REBOOT and MASTER_CLEAR permission. Even tried setting my app as device owner and wipe data through DevicePolicyManager. But still got exception from RecoverySystem.bootcommand

Comment: Have you also add android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in your AndroidManifest?